# Logger does not work anymore after upgrade from Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, logging

Since I've upgraded to Laravel version 5.6 from Laravel version 5.5 my Logger doesn't work properly anymore.

At first I got the following error stack :

```
laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /home/vagrant/Code/grotesmurf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:181)
```

which was solved by simply adding the new `config/logging.php` file that is provided by Laravel 5.6.

But now I'm getting no output from the Logger! I'm simply running `\Log::info('hello!')` as a tinker command, but it doesn't generate any log output anymore (same for scripts calling the \Log() method).

I've tried different LOG_CHANNEL settings (daily, single, stack), but none of these work.

Hope anyone has ran into this error already and is able to provide me with some suggestions. I have followed the upgrade guide and it doesn't help unfortunately.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm running php version 7.1 & am on ubuntu.

P.P.S. I have cleared all cached config using artisan.

Comment: Try editing `config/logging.php` to your needs, try changing default logger to `single`.

Comment: Did you follow the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade)? Especially the section on Logging?

Comment: @Kyslik I have adjusted it using my .env file, as stated I have tried using 3 different channels that are available, but none seems to generate an output.

Comment: @kerbholz As I have stated, yes I have followed the upgrade guide, doesn't seem to help.. It does work on a new Laravel 5.6 project though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the actual problem, we use an adjusted `storage_path()` method in our application and the new Logger is now using the `storage_path()` method to generate its path - this caused the log file to be created in a different directory than `storage/logs`.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, deleting the files in bootstrap/cache solved it.